# How to stop TStack.pop from freeing popped object

Tags: delphi

I was implementing a stack using the Delphi TStack from Generics.Collections (under Delphi XE) and noticed that when I call pop, the popped object gets freed which doesn't seem to make sense to me as I cannot now use the popped object. Instead I found I could use Extract which seems to work. My question is, is there any way I can use pop instead as it aids readability of the code. Is there some way to stop it from freeing the popped object?

As a side note, I thought of using TObjectStack as that allows me to control who owns the objects but then I discovered that the TObjectStack pop is a method that doesn't actually return what was popped so it's not very useful.

Comment: Could you show us a bit of your code?  This code works as expected: Stack := TStack<TStringList>.Create;  Stack.Push(TStringList.Create);    Stack.Peek.Add('');  Caption := IntToStr(Stack.Pop.Count);

Comment: I traced the code directly into the rtl source and observed my object being freed in the notify call. Extract doesn't do that. I will set up a simple example to see if the same thing happens and report back. Did you try popping the tstringlist off the stack and check if it was still a valid object?

Comment: Yes, I've checked that object is not nil and it's contents is valid.

Comment: are you sure ? in my XE2 all it does is *procedure TStack<T>.Notify(const Item: T; Action: TCollectionNotification);
begin
  if Assigned(FOnNotify) then
    FOnNotify(Self, Item, Action);
end;* So it only can free it if you do it yourself in your event handler. Are you having List of Objects or List of Interfaces ?  Maybe you could use Spring4D stack then ?

Comment: The reason why TObjectStack<T>.Pop is not a function is just because the popped object is freed inside Notify (use Peek/Pop or Extract). But I cannot see this behaviour in a simple TStack<T>, unless someone implemented it in the OnNotify event.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for commenting. I discovered that it was TObjectStack.Notify that was being called not TStack.Notify, hence the freeing of the object. I built a test system using TStack and that worked. The problem 'fixed' itself in my main application when I restarted Delphi and did a new build. Last night I hadn't noticed it was calling TObjectStack.Notify. Originally I had tried to use TObjectStack but because pop is a method in that class and doesn't return the popped object I switched to TStack. For some reason the TObjectStack.Pop was still begin called instead of TStack.Pop.

Comment: The reason for `TObjectStack.Pop` being called is that the object you made was a `TObjectStack` and was not a `TStack`.